# How to adjust UV mapping for each element of an array?

Tags: texturing, uv, modifiers

I am using an array in conjunction with a curve modifier to make a stone wall along a path.  But the problem is that it is easily noticeable that all the stones have the exact same mapping (i.e. the exact same cracks in the exact same place) which looks terrible.  This problem is easy to eradicate for just the displace modifier by basing the texture coordinates on an empty.  I would like to be able to do something like this for the material mapping as well, altering the position of the UV pelt on the UV grid.  Though I am open to any suggestions on how to fix this problem.

**Edit:**

As a clarification, I need to use *UV* coordinates, *not generated*.

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles?

Comment: @gandalf3 I am using Cycles.  I have currently applied all modifiers and have manually adjusted the UV map.  It works but the viewport is massively slow since I had to apply the subsurf at the render subdivisions.  So I am still open to suggestions.

Comment: It's possible to tweak the UV mapping slightly based on location etc, but for writing an exact answer it would be useful to know what the precise use-case/current setup is. e.g. is it a reasonable random texture which can be positioned arbitrarily (e.g. stone)? Are you using blended box mapping? Or flat mapping? Why do you need to use UV coordinates?

Comment: @gandalf3 I have a rectangular box with a few loop cuts to make square faces.  It then has subsurf, array, and bend modifiers.  For some reason all of the mapping coordinates other than UV produce very bad streaking.  Slightly tweaking the coordinates would work just fine, it is just a simple stone texture.  Also, I am not using blended box mapping, though I could if need be.

Comment: I think blended box mapping will get rid of the streaking problems. I'll add an answer when this gets reopened..